# Key input ignored on repeated key press for 0.5 seconds

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1
some point recently something changed and now when i press a key any additional presses of that key are ignored for about half a second - except that it resets the waiting period.
This makes arrow key navigation  hard and causes a lot of typos in words that use the same leter 2x in a row.

It happens with both the built in, and my external keyboard.

I tried tweaking the key repeat settings in accessability but that has no efect

Comment: Seems related to/same as https://askubuntu.com/q/231481/229393 but the option used to fix there is gone

Answer (score 1):

Bounce Keys  accessibility setting seems to have been mistakenly turned on.

This Ignored Fast repeated key presses.

Turn it off by following these instructions from the [Ubuntu docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/a11y-bouncekeys.html.en)
but at the end selecting off rather than on.

1. Open the Settings.
2. Click Accessibility in the sidebar to open the panel.
3. Press Typing Assist (AccessX) in the Typing section.
4. Switch the Bounce Keys switch to off.

[image: Image showing the AccessX settings, bounce keys is on the bottom]